# gravar texto no arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou usando esse código para gravar no arquivo:

```
try(BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(caminho, formato)){

            bw.write("frase teste\n");
            bw.write("outra coisa");

        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Mas ele não reconhece o caractere. Como resolvo?

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
 try(BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(caminho, formato)){

    bw.write("frase teste");
    bw.newLine();
    bw.write("outra coisa");

 }catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()